# MySQL displays "Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)". When I try to access it using Golang gorm package

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

This the app.go file I used

```
package config

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
)

var db *gorm.DB

func Connect() {
    dsn := "<root>:<password>@/simplerest?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
    d, err := gorm.Open("mysql", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        log.Fatal("Connection established")
    }

    fmt.Printf("Type : %T", d)
    db = d
}

func GetDB() *gorm.DB {
    return db
}
```

I always get the error when i try to run my app.go file

```
panic: Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/bedLad/go-bookstore/pkg/config.Connect()
        /home/root/development/go-code/go-bookstore/pkg/config/app.go:17 +0x12a
github.com/bedLad/go-bookstore/pkg/models.init.0()
        /home/root/development/go-code/go-bookstore/pkg/models/book.go:22 +0x19
exit status 2
```

I can access mySQL via my terminal using the command
`mysql -u root -p`
So password is not a problem at all

Comment: You shouldn't use root in an application. Create a dedicated user with the right permissions

Answer (score 0):

format your dsn as follows:

```golang
 dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s", user, password, hostname, port, dbname) + "?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
  db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
      return
  } else {
    fmt.Println("Connected")
  }
```

Comment: Why would adjusting the DSN help here?

Comment: @DarkBee i am not just adjusting dsn but also connecting to db with a different syntax, this had helped me in past  so i thought this might help OP